# Aws Lambda O.K but on my M1 return error. :(

Tags: docker, lambda, selenium-chromedriver, apple-m1, amazon-ecr

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8.2023.03.29.13-x86_64 as build

RUN yum install -y unzip && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver.zip" "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/112.0.5615.28/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chrome-linux.zip" "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1100514%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1675363434858111&alt=media" && \ 
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt/ && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux.zip -d /opt/


#FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8.2023.03.28.15
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8.2023.03.29.13-x86_64

RUN yum install atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib \
    libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver \
    libXtst pango at-spi2-atk libXt xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
    xorg-x11-xauth dbus-glib dbus-glib-devel -y

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install beautifulsoup4
# RUN pip install pymysql
RUN pip install selenium

COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux /opt/chrome

COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver /opt/

COPY *.py ./

CMD [ "farmair_scraping.test_func" ]
```

I built the above code with this cmd

[docker build --platform linux/x86_64 -t farmair_scraping .  ],

and push it to ecr. it worked. Good.

And then, I tried to run the image on my M1 with a cmd

[docker run --platform linux/x86_64 -p 9000:8080 farmair_scraping]

[curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}']

but I got an error message

"Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /opt/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

I feel like smashing my M1 into pieces... M1 always got in trouble with docker.

Comment: Have you tried the arm64 build?

Answer (score 1):

In your `FROM` statement you explicitly tag `x86_64` image favour. Use the `arm64` one locally.